# Stop repeating timer android

Tags: android

I want to create 10 `ImageViews` with a delay of 5 seconds between, I created this code:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (counter <= 10)
            newimg();
        else
        // here I want to stop the timer so it will not try to create any more `ImageViews`   (the array contains only 10).
    }
}, 0, 5000);

private void newimg() {
    ball[counter] = new ImageView(this);
    ball[counter].setTag(counter);
    ball[counter].setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
    int randomx = rand.nextInt(layoutwidth);
    int randomy = rand.nextInt(layoutheight);
    ball[counter].setX(randomx);
    ball[counter].setY(randomy);
    rlt.addView(ball[counter]);
    counter++;
}
```

How can I stop the timer inside the else statement?

Comment: Call **cencel()** method to Cancels the Timer and all scheduled tasks.

Comment: @visheshchandra So I should write there `this.cancel();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `cancel()` on timer

---

My Solutions is :

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(createImageView, 5000);

 Runnable createImageView=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (counter <= 10){
               handler.postDelayed(this,5000);
               newimg();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: What are the advantages of using Handler and not TimerTask?

Comment: see this link http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/12/handler-vs-timer-fixed-period-execution.html

Comment: And after it will get to 10, the handler will stop running?

Comment: yes, because we are scheduling again if condition is true

Answer (score 2):

Call [Timer cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29) to stop the timer.